# Get rows from child and from its child table

Tags: mysql

I want to get rows from child and from it's child table in MySQL.

Supposed I have the following tables with their columns:

**Table product**

```
id 
name 
created
```

**Table inventory**

```
id
tableA_id 
created
```

**Table expiry**

```
id 
tableB_id
```

Relationships:

- table A is the parent table
- table B is child of table A
- table C is child of table B
- `tableA_id` is foreign key to table A
- `tableB_id` is foreign key to table B

Basically, I just want to get rows from

- table B where created from table A is 30 days older
- table C where id not exist in table B

Is this possible? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for editing @Ezlo. I'm new here so not yet aware with formatting for questions.

Comment: It would be more precise to provide `SHOW CREATE TABLEs`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `product` is `table A`, `inventory` is `table B` and `expiry` is `table C` (i don't know why you generalized them), these would be the queries you can use for your 2 requirements.

- table B where created from table A is 30 days older

  ```
  SELECT
      I.*
  FROM
      product P
      INNER JOIN inventory I ON P.id = I.tableA_id
  WHERE
      DATEDIFF(I.created, P.created) > 30 -- Assuming that product is created before inventory)
  ```
- table C where id not exist in table B

  ```
  SELECT
      P.*
  FROM
      expiry P
  WHERE
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'not in inventory' FROM inventory I WHERE I.id = P.tableB_id)
  ```

I suggest changing the foreign key's column names to their actual table (if you actually have them that way). `tableA_id` to `productID` and `tableB_id` to `inventoryID`.